# calculate peak values in a plot using R

Tags: r

I have a table with two variables.The data is from NMR.So when I plot I get a spectrum.I found the peaks in plot.But I need to know how to list the values of peak and store them into a variable.Anyone please help.

Comment: It might help if you could show a small selection of your data to play with.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. However, I suggest looking at the msProcess package. It provides lots of interesting functions.

Comment: What about something like this? http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=simecol:peaks

Comment: I used peak function to find the peaks in plot.Even then i cant find the peaks with higher frequency value.The peak function is predicting even very small peaks in the plot.The peak function i used is peaks<-function(series,span=3){ z <- embed(series, span) s <- span%/%2 v<- max.col(z) == 1 + s result <- c(rep(FALSE,s),v) result <- result[1:(length(result)-s)] result } plot(ppm,freq, type="l") p <- which(peaks(freq, span=3)) points(ppm[p], freq[p], col="red")

Comment: The example data is in the following link               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908553/how-to-find-peaks-in-r-plots.Please some one answer this.

Comment: I can only reiterate that there are packages that provide (somewhat more sofisticated) functions for peak detection. A quick google search even found me a package for evaluation of NMR data: http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/BQuant/BQuant_1.0_Manual.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But after installing BQuant package when i load the package it shows following error                          **Error: package ‘BQuant’ is not installed for 'arch=i386'**       Can you please sort it out.

Answer (score 5):

An easy implementation based on Brian Ripley's post at [R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-January/010704.html):

```
peaks <- function(x, halfWindowSize) {

  windowSize <- halfWindowSize * 2 + 1
  windows <- embed(x, windowSize)
  localMaxima <- max.col(windows, "first") == halfWindowSize + 1

  return(c(rep(FALSE, halfWindowSize), localMaxima, rep(FALSE, halfWindowSize)))
}
```

Example:

```
x <- c(1,3,1,3,1)

peaks(x, 1)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```